# How can I create a two-element object with Groovy's JsonBuilder?

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

In my Groovy code, I've got two variables declared:

`results` is an array of maps. It contains a list of rows returned from a SQL query.

`overall` is a map. It represents a single row of a separate SQL query.

I want to combine these two variables into one and output the whole thing as JSON. In the end, I want it to look something like this:

```
{"data":[{"results":"array"}],"overall":{"overall":"map"}}
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use, but it doesn't work:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
def finalJSON = json {
    data results
    overall overall
}

return json.toString()
```

But this doesn't work... it throws the following exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: call for class: groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult
```

I can verify that both variables `results` and `overall` have the correct data in them. I guess I'm just not understanding the syntax for JsonBuilder.

Comment: where is the error thrown?  what exactly are results and overall?  some SQL results I figure.  But what have you done to transform so far etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find possible solutions below:

```
import groovy.json.*

def r = [[l:1],[l:2]]
def o = [over:1,all:2]

def json = new JsonBuilder()

json {
    data r
    overall o
}
println json.toPrettyString()

def m = [data: r, overall: o]

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(m))
```

Comment: no, there is no root needed.  just remove the `all` in your example and it still works and the result is what OP wants.  there is something wrong with the data sent into the builder (toString vs actual data)

Comment: Thanks @cfrick, it works! Maybe I've failed somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. Groovy's kind of stupid in that you apparently cannot use the same variable name for the value as the key you're assigning. So the real trouble was with the line that read:

```
overall overall
```

I changed that variable to `overallData` and everything started working.